# Notifications for edits by others of my own questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, notifications, information-display

I'd like to be more aware of when other SOpedians edit my own questions and answers, which is sure to happen because my innate spelling and grammar skills are  overloaded by my vocabulary and lackadaisical proofreading habits.  That said, I would like to review edits to my posts to ensure the basic content has not changed.

What do folks think of this?

EDIT:

So, apparently there is the revisions tab, which I had not seen.  But revisions are not in the summary page, which I'd like to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was not technically completed -- although you could manually view edits as Kyle notes, **the envelope did not turn red when your posts were edited by another user**.

Now it does, so it is *truly* completed.

Answer (score 4):

This is already possible. Just click the envelope at the next to your username at the top of the screen. The "Revisions" tab contains the edits other people made to your posts during the selected time period.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh....ok...never saw that, cool.  But I think I'd still like the mail icon to turn red too.  And revisions are not in the summary.