# Poke user feature request

Tags: feature-request, users

Quite often I find myself writing comments like =>

> Please, check my question for details.

I find them quite useless and redundant in general.

It might be a good idea to add feature with which I could *poke* those users who have posted an answer (some more constraints are likely to be added).

What do you think?

Comment: Why do you want to get physical with users? Can you go nowhere anymore without being assaulted?

Comment: 1- I don't. 2- I'm not sure about that.

Comment: perhaps you were thinking http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers ??

Comment: Question wasn't about poking everybody. I don't use facebook and english is not my native and therefore - that word does not sound arrogant for me. It was about reducing useless and noise making comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

But seriously:

- [Notifications for edits by others of my own questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers)
- [Notify us when an answer we've accepted has been edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/notify-us-when-an-answer-weve-accepted-has-been-edited)
- [Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer)