# No notification when a question or answer is revised?

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notifications for edits by others of my own questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers)

Maybe I missed it but it seems we don't get notifications when one of our questions or answers is edited by someone else.  Seems like this would be an important event to notify users about.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers

Comment: Apparently this is `status-completed` so let's see if you get notified on this question.

Comment: This is not really a dup.  I opened a new question that is clearer why it's not a dup.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41507/notification-when-a-question-or-answer-is-revised-is-not-really-status-completed

Answer (score 0):

In the 'envelope' window (`http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/<yourid>`), there is a 'Revisions' tab which has entries if your question or answer is revised by someone else.