# Notification when a question or answer is revised is not really status-completed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, revisions-list

This question about notifications of revisions is marked `status-completed`:

[Notifications for edits by others of my own questions and answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/notifications-for-edits-by-others-of-my-own-questions-and-answers)

But it's not really completed.  The envelope turns red but you don't get the drop-down notification box that says "You've had 3 edits to your questions" or something similar.  We get this for answers and comments, but not revisions.

This info is available in the revisions tab, so it's not totally hidden, but the ability to hunt down this information is not the same as notifications.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6986

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6986/add-a-notification-when-one-of-your-questions-get-a-status-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed - [see Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/you-have-1-new-answer-see-your-responses-link-doesnt-show-any-responses/44167#44167) for details!

Also, these specific "header notifications" are added on a longer delay than the "new message envelope" alerts.  Perhaps this update time could be a user preference?

Answer (score -2):

The envelope turning red **is** a notification.  It's much less intrusive than the drop-down badge/response notification.

Comment: The envelope is a notification that something happened, no indication of what.  I'm asking for the intrusive drop-down.  SO pops it down for answers/comments, I would argue revisions are just as important.